# Perl XML::Twig find single node nested

Tags: xml, perl

How selecte singelnode nestet with Twig. and holdet by my $var =? (in the future so i can add math formula) (With Shell was : $xbcom = (xml$xdxml).selectSingleNode("city/bases/@com").$xt)

```
#!perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

use XML::Twig;
my $t = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
    twig_handlers => {
        'city/name' => sub { print $_[1]->text, "\n"; },
        'city/population' => sub { print "Pop: ", $_[1]->text, "\n"; },
    }
);
$t->parseurl('http://athome.myminicity.com/xml');
```

---

#### Expected XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><city>
  <host>athome.myminicity.com</host>
  <name>AtHome</name>
  <region code="FR">france</region>
  <ranking>2</ranking>
  <population>19038934</population>
  <incomes>-2147483648</incomes>
  <unemployment>0</unemployment>
  <transport>100</transport>
  <criminality>0</criminality>
  <pollution>0</pollution>
  <nextnuke>1</nextnuke>
  <signatures>0</signatures>
  <bases com="381162" env="4118994" ind="6219447" sec="4759785" tra="3807867"/>
</city>
```

I have work on:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

use XML::Twig;
my $t= XML::Twig->new(pretty_print => 'indented',
                    twig_handlers => {
                          'city/name'=>sub{  print "      ",$_->text,"-Mmc\n\n"; },
                          'city/population'=>sub{  print "      Population: ",$_->text,"\n"; },
                          'city/bases'=>sub{  print "      Commerce: ",$_->att('com'),"; Environ: ",$_->att('env'),"; Security: ",$_->att('sec'),"; transport: ",$_->att('tra'),"; Industrie: ",$_->att('ind'),"\n\n", },
                    }
);

## Html future ....
print "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";

## Intro
print "\n      XML Data Info:\n\r\n";

## Date time stamp
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$day,$month,$yr19,@rest) =   localtime(time); 
print "      Date:\t$day-".++$month. "-".($yr19+1900)."\n"; 
print "      Time:\t".sprintf("%02d",$hour).":".sprintf("%02d",$min).":".sprintf("%02d",$sec)."\n\n"; 

## Result (processe)
$t->parseurl('http://athome.myminicity.com/xml');
```

But I don't find all @r

Comment: You seem to have made very little effort to write a clear and concise question, and it doesn't appear to be because you are struggling with the English language

Comment: just because perl can be written in a single line doesn't mean we want to read it as such.

Comment: @Borodin, Thanks for your reply! I don't no with tidy. At this moment all is to news for me. @r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you're looking for:

```
city/bases/@com
```

That's an xpath expression, which extracts the attribute 'com' from the element `city/bases`.

So the way you could access this with `XML::Twig` is

```
#!perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

use XML::Twig;
my $t = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
    twig_handlers => {
        '/city/name' => sub { print $_->text, "\n"; },
        '/city/population' => sub { print "Pop: ", $_->text, "\n"; },
        '/city/bases' => sub { print "Bases com: ", $_->att('com'), "\n" },
    }
);
$t->parseurl ( 'http://athome.myminicity.com/xml' );
```

You may want to extend the sub a little to test for the existence of that attribute, but that hopefully gives you an idea of how it could work? What may be useful to know - `XML::Twig` parses two sets of data into it's handlers:

`@_` is `$twig`, and `$element`.

`$_` is `$element`.

So you don't need to `$_[1]` there.

This will print each instance of a matching attribute, rather than a single one, but I'm sure you can figure out how to deal with that if you need to.

However you probably don't want to use `twig_handlers` for this job at all:

```
my $city = $t->root;
print "Name: ", $city->field('name'),       "\n";
print "Pop:",   $city->field('population'), "\n";
print "COM:",   $city->first_child('bases')->att('com'), "\n";
```

Or to answer what I think is your question:

```
my $xbcom = $t -> root -> first_child('bases') -> att('com');
```

Comment: The paths should be looking only in the root of the data, so `/city/name` etc.

Comment: @Sobrique, many thanks for your stuff!. Thats wath I would " my $xbcom = $t -> root -> first_child('bases') -> att('com');" @r

Comment: To all, Please can you give any link with good explication (handlers... to explore expressions? @r

Comment: @Arnold: There is no need to use callbacks with `XML::Twig` unless your data is huge and will not fit in memory.

Comment: @mirod: Are you recommending that as a resource?

Comment: @Borodin yes, it's all a bit old but the module hasn't changed that much in a while. The Changes file in the distribution is also a good resource, especially if you have been using the module for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what your question means, but it looks like this will at least fetch your data

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI;
use XML::Twig;

my $url = URI->new('http://athome.myminicity.com/xml');

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;

$twig->parseurl($url);

for my $city ( $twig->findnodes('/city') ) {

  printf "City:       %s\n", $city->field('name');
  printf "Population: %s\n", $city->field('population');

  my $bases = $city->first_child('bases');
  print "Bases:\n";
  for my $base ( sort $bases->att_names ) {
    printf "  %s = %s\n", $base, $bases->att($base);
  }

}
```

#### output

```
City:       AtHome
Population: 19039137
Bases:
  com = 381162
  env = 4119042
  ind = 6219519
  sec = 4759834
  tra = 3807909
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your sugestion! You present me "Table version". But how you isolat each value in differ variable? Ex./ $var1, $var2 .... (7 variables)? Thanks @r

Comment: ,Thanks.But this is "table version" How you us subroutines or function for each value-(7 diff values)? @r